# How to mark the center and calculate the diameter of an image using opencv - python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am working on the recognition of the center and the image rendering. I'm using `cv2.findContours` to delimit the edges of the image of interest. And using `cv.minEnclosingCircle (cnt)` to circumnavigate my region of interest. The code below I can identify the center of each ROI, but I am not able to mark in the output of the image the circle corresponding to the image that I want to calculate and also I want to mark with a pqno point the exact location where the algorithm identified the center.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText


thresh = cv2.imread('IMD044.png',0)
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
print (len(contours))
cnt = contours

for i in range (len(cnt)):
    (x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt[i])
    center = (int(x),int(y))
    radius = int(radius)
    cv2.circle(thresh,center,radius,(0,255,0),2)
    print ('Circle: ' + str(i) + ' - Center: ' + str(center) + ' -     Radius: ' + str(radius))
plt.text(x-15, y+10, '+', fontsize=25, color = 'red')
plt.text(10, -10, 'Centro: '+str(center), fontsize=11, color = 'red')
plt.text(340, -10, 'Diametro: '+str((radius*2)/100)+'mm', fontsize=11, color = 'red')
plt.Circle(x, y, color='red', fill=False)
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

I used the [Opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) documentation to demarcate the contours and get the regions, but the green circle mark does not appear.

Exit:

[image]

Exit expected:
[image]

updating the question I was able to add the information, it's only necessary to add the circle and check if the diameter is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single channel image, but trying to show 3-channel color. Add the following:

```
...
thresh = cv2.imread('IMD016.png',0)
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
thresh = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
print (len(contours))
...
```

Also, be extra careful when mixing the `OpenCV` and `PyPlot` drawing routines. `OpenCV` uses `BGR` by default, while `PyPlot` uses `RGB`. Also, `cv2` drawing routines don't add extra channels, while the `plt` does. Just need to keep that in mind

Comment: I saw that I updated the question. Is the above code correct to measure the diameter of the region of interest? yes, I just need to add the circle to the plot, I'm trying here

Comment: I understand, I'm learning now to work with opencv. While to the diameter of the image, the code described above is correct? Can you help me about this?

Comment: I believe this is a diameter of the contour in terms of **pixels**. pixels don't automatically convert to `mm`

Comment: hey guy, I discovered that my cv2.imshow is no longer displaying any output image, it happened after I updated the version of opencv to 4. What will happen? I already researched in several corners, and some people going through it, but no answer. Eh so, I can not get outputs in the algorithm above.

Comment: If you want to convert the diameter to mm, you need to know the `dpi` of the image. `diameter_in_mm = dpi * 3.93701 * diameter_in_pixels`. Of course, this is assuming `1 dpi = 0.393701 pixel/cm`

Comment: who would the diameter_in_pixels be?

Comment: `(x,y),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt[i]); diameter_in_pixels = radius * 2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183591/discussion-between-tecnologia-da-net-and-rafazz).